# Does $ K (f (x)) \cong K (x) $ hold as a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $ K $ be a field and $ f (x) \in K [x] $ be a non-constant polynomial.
Does $ K (f (x)) \cong K (x) $ hold as a field?

This is an unexpected fact for me, but I couldn't construct a counterexample, so I thought it is correct.

Comment: Yes. Basically, $f(x)$ is not a root of any polynomial $h(x)\in K(x).$ $x$ is transcendental over $K,$ pretty much by definition.

Comment: More generally, if $K\subseteq K’,$ and $\alpha\in K’$ is not algebraic over $K,$ then $K(\alpha)\cong K(x).$

Comment: I was convinced. I was confused because $ [K (x): K (f (x))] = \deg (f) $.